# FQL - search array of comments in stream

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

When I pull search results from the stream table, one of the components returned is an array of comments. I was wondering if there is any way of searching based on the text of the comments in the comments array?

Here is my query. It works fine in its current form:

```
    SELECT post_id, attribution, message, description, comments.comment_list.text, likes,
     place, permalink, message_tags, message,  description_tags, type
    FROM stream WHERE filter_key in 
    (SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE uid=me()) 
    AND 
    (
    (strpos(lower(message), 'college football') >= 0) OR 
    (strpos(lower(description), 'college football') >= 0) OR 
    (strpos(lower(attribution), 'college football') >= 0)
    )
    order by created_time desc
```

The **comments.comment_list.text** results for one of the returned rows look like this:

```
    "comments": {
            "comment_list": [
             {
                "text": "I love college football"
             },
             {
                "text": "Alabama and LSU rule college football"
             }
             ]
    }
```

My question is: Is there any way for me to also search in the **comments.comment_list.text** in the same way as I do for **message**, **description**, and **attribution** above? When I tried to add something like the following:

```
    (strpos(lower(comments.comment_list.text), 'college football') >= 0)
```

I got an empty dataset (interestingly, I do not get any errors, just empty results). I can see why, since I would need to somehow be able to iterate through the array of comments and then retrieve their text and do a comparison on the text of the comment. I would like to do this with FQL on the Facebook end and would like to avoid retrieving all the results and then iterating through them on my end. Any ideas or suggestions on how I may be able to do that?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2):

The `comments` field in the `stream` table only retrieves a subset of the comments. I think the limit is 5. That, and searching through arrays returned by FQL seems like it should be easy. It isn't.

The best thing to do is to convert this to a multiquery. For your results, you'll want to look at the `#combined` data only.

```
{'all_posts':
   'SELECT post_id FROM stream WHERE filter_key in 
    (SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE uid=me())',
 'commented':
    'SELECT post_id FROM comment WHERE post_id IN (SELECT post_id FROM #all_posts)
      AND (strpos(lower(text), 'college football') >= 0',
 'combined':
    'SELECT post_id, attribution, message, description, comments.comment_list.text, likes,
      place, permalink, message_tags, message,  description_tags, type
      FROM stream WHERE post_id IN (SELECT post_id FROM #all_posts) AND 
       (
        (strpos(lower(message), 'college football') >= 0) OR 
        (strpos(lower(description), 'college football') >= 0) OR 
        (strpos(lower(attribution), 'college football') >= 0)
       )
     OR post_id IN (SELECT post_id FROM #commented)
    order by created_time desc'
}
```